# Escape html data inside JSON string using PHP or WordPress

Tags: php, json, wordpress

I have table in which the values are stored in the JSON format.

```
{"0":{"panel-1":{"type":"panel","panel_width":["700",320],"map_style":{"0":{"parameter":"width","unit":"px","name":"panel_width"},"1":{"parameter":"height","unit":"px","name":"panel_height"},"2":{"parameter":"inherit_bg","name":"inherit_bg_prop"},"3":{"parameter":"background_type","name":"background_type"},"4":{"parameter":"lighten_color","name":"panel_lighter_color"},"5":{"parameter":"darken-color","name":"panel_darker_color"},"6":{"parameter":"gradient_lighter_location","name":"gradient_lighter_location"},"7":{"parameter":"gradient_darker_location","name":"gradient_darker_location"},"8":{"parameter":"panel_gradient_type","name":"panel_gradient_type"},"9":{"parameter":"radial_gradient_direction","name":"radial_panel_gradient_direction"},"10":{"parameter":"gradient_angle","name":"gradient_angle"},"11":{"parameter":"background-color","name":"panel_background_color"},"12":{"parameter":"background-image","name":"panel_bg_image"},"13":{"parameter":"background_opt","name":"opt_bg"},"14":{"parameter":"panel_img_overlay_color","name":"panel_img_overlay_color"},"15":{"parameter":"overlay-gradient-type","name":"overlay_gradient_type"},"16":{"parameter":"overlay_lighter_color","name":"overlay_lighter_color"},"17":{"parameter":"overlay_lighter_location","name":"overlay_lighter_location"},"18":{"parameter":"overlay-darker-color","name":"overlay_darker_color"},"19":{"parameter":"overlay_darker_location","name":"overlay_darker_location"},"20":{"parameter":"overlay_panel_gradient_type","name":"overlay_panel_gradient_type"},"21":{"parameter":"radial_overlay_gradient_direction","name":"radial_overlay_gradient_direction"},"22":{"parameter":"overlay_gradient_angle","name":"overlay_gradient_angle"},"23":{"parameter":"overlay-color","name":"panel_overlay_color"},"24":{"parameter":"entry_animation","name":"panel_entry_animation"},"25":{"parameter":"border-style","name":"panel_border_style"},"26":{"parameter":"border-color","name":"panel_border_color"},"27":{"parameter":"border-width","name":"panel_border_width"},"28":{"parameter":"border-radius","name":"panel_border_radius"},"29":{"parameter":"box-shadow","name":"panel_box_shadow"},"30":{"parameter":"mobile-breakpoint","name":"cp_mobile_br_point"}},"panel_height":["400",480],"inherit_bg_prop":"1","background_type":["color"],"panel_lighter_color":["#fff"],"panel_darker_color":["#ddd"],"gradient_lighter_location":["0"],"gradient_darker_location":["100"],"panel_gradient_type":["lineargradient"],"radial_panel_gradient_direction":["center_center"],"gradient_angle":["180"],"panel_background_color":["#fff"],"panel_bg_image":["0|modules/img/grey.png"],"opt_bg":["repeat|center|contain"],"panel_img_overlay_color":["rgba(0,0,0,0.12)"],"overlay_gradient_type":"color","overlay_lighter_color":"rgba(255,255,255,0.9)","overlay_lighter_location":"0","overlay_darker_color":"rgba(221,221,221,0.9)","overlay_darker_location":"100","overlay_panel_gradient_type":"lineargradient","radial_overlay_gradient_direction":"center_center","overlay_gradient_angle":"180","panel_overlay_color":"rgba(0,0,0,0.8)","close_overlay_click":"1","panel_entry_animation":"cp-fadeIn","panel_border_style":"none","panel_border_color":"#e1e1e1","panel_border_width":"1|1|1|1|px|1","panel_border_radius":"3|3|3|3|px|1","panel_box_shadow":"type:none|horizontal:0|vertical:0|blur:5|spread:0|color:rgba(86,86,131,0.6)","shadow_type":"none","cp_mobile_br_point":"767"},"form_field":{"type":"form_field","form_field_font":"inherit:inherit","map_style":{"0":{"parameter":"font-family","name":"form_field_font"},"1":{"parameter":"font-size","unit":"px","name":"form_field_font_size"},"2":{"parameter":"letter-spacing","name":"form_field_letter_spacing"},"3":{"parameter":"text-align","name":"form_field_text_align"},"4":{"parameter":"color","name":"form_field_color"},"5":{"parameter":"color","target":"placeholder","name":"form_field_placeholder_color"},"6":{"parameter":"background-color","name":"form_field_bg_color"},"7":{"parameter":"border-style","name":"form_field_border_style"},"8":{"parameter":"border-width","name":"form_field_border_width"},"9":{"parameter":"border-radius","name":"form_field_border_radius"},"10":{"parameter":"border-color","name":"form_field_border_color"},"11":{"parameter":"active-border-color","name":"form_field_active_border_color"},"12":{"parameter":"box-shadow","name":"form_field_box_shadow"},"13":{"parameter":"padding","name":"form_field_padding"}},"form_field_font_size":["13"],"form_field_letter_spacing":["0"],"form_field_text_align":["left"],"form_field_color":"#666","form_field_placeholder_color":"#666","form_field_bg_color":"#fff","form_field_border_style":"solid","form_field_border_width":"1|1|1|1|px|1","form_field_border_radius":"1|1|1|1|px|1","form_field_border_color":"#bbb","form_field_active_border_color":"#666","form_field_box_shadow":"type:none|horizontal:0|vertical:0|blur:5|spread:0|color:rgba(86,86,131,0.6)","shadow_type":"none","form_field_padding":["0|10|0|10|px|0"]},"cp_email-2":{"position":[{"x":235,"y":60.5,"right":"no","bottom":"no"}],"layerindex":2,"map_style":{"3":{"name":"field_animation","parameter":"removeAnimClass","onhover":false,"target":".cp-field-html-data","unit":"data-anim-class"},"6":{"name":"width","parameter":"width","onhover":false,"target":false,"unit":"px"},"7":{"name":"height","parameter":"height","onhover":false,"target":false,"unit":"px"}},"map":{"0":{"name":"email_text_placeholder","attr":"placeholder","target":".cp-target"},"1":{"name":"label_as_placeholder","attr":"label-as-placeholder","target":".cp-target"},"2":{"name":"required","attr":"required","target":".cp-target"},"3":{"name":"field_animation","attr":"data-anim-class","target":".cp-field-html-data"},"4":{"name":"field_animation_delay","attr":"data-anim-delay","target":".cp-field-html-data"},"5":{"name":"field_animation_duration","attr":"data-anim-duration","target":".cp-field-html-data"}},"type":"cp_email","email_text_placeholder":"Email","label_as_placeholder":"true","required":"true","field_animation":"cp-none","field_animation_delay":"0ms","field_animation_duration":"1000ms","width":["230"],"height":["45"]},"cp_textarea-2":{"position":[{"x":235,"y":128.5,"right":"no","bottom":"no"}],"layerindex":3,"map_style":{"4":{"name":"textarea_padding","parameter":"padding","onhover":"","target":".cp-target","unit":"px"},"7":{"name":"width","parameter":"width","onhover":false,"target":false,"unit":"px"},"8":{"name":"height","parameter":"height","onhover":false,"target":false,"unit":"px"}},"map":{"0":{"name":"input_text_name","attr":"name","target":".cp-target"},"1":{"name":"input_text_placeholder","attr":"placeholder","target":".cp-target"},"2":{"name":"label_as_placeholder","attr":"label-as-placeholder","target":".cp-target"},"3":{"name":"required","attr":"required","target":".cp-target"},"4":{"name":"field_animation","attr":"data-anim-class","target":".cp-field-html-data"},"5":{"name":"field_animation_delay","attr":"data-anim-delay","target":".cp-field-html-data"},"6":{"name":"field_animation_duration","attr":"data-anim-duration","target":".cp-field-html-data"}},"type":"cp_textarea","input_text_name":"textarea_2534","input_text_placeholder":"Enter message here","label_as_placeholder":"true","required":"false","field_animation":"cp-none","field_animation_delay":"0ms","field_animation_duration":"1000ms","width":["230"],"height":["120"],"textarea_padding":"0|10|0|10|px|0"},"cp_checkbox-2":{"position":[{"x":235,"y":263.5,"right":"no","bottom":"no"}],"layerindex":4,"map_style":{"2":{"name":"checkbox_options","parameter":"checkbox-options","unit":"","onhover":false,"target":false},"4":{"name":"checkbox_orientation","parameter":"checkbox-orientation","onhover":false,"target":false,"unit":""},"5":{"name":"label_line_height","parameter":"line-height","onhover":false,"target":".cp-target","unit":""},"6":{"name":"field_animation","parameter":"removeAnimClass","onhover":false,"target":".cp-field-html-data","unit":"data-anim-class"},"9":{"name":"width","parameter":"width","onhover":false,"target":false,"unit":"px"},"10":{"name":"height","parameter":"height","onhover":false,"target":false,"unit":"px"}},"map":{"0":{"name":"checkbox_name","attr":"name","target":".cp-target"},"1":{"name":"input_text_placeholder","attr":"placeholder","target":".cp-target"},"3":{"name":"required","attr":"required","target":".cp-target"},"6":{"name":"field_animation","attr":"data-anim-class","target":".cp-field-html-data"},"7":{"name":"field_animation_delay","attr":"data-anim-delay","target":".cp-field-html-data"},"8":{"name":"field_animation_duration","attr":"data-anim-duration","target":".cp-field-html-data"}},"type":"cp_checkbox","checkbox_name":"checkboxfield_3472","input_text_placeholder":"Placeholder text"
```

`,"checkbox_options":"<a href="dhjhsfjhdj">Option1</a>",`

`"required":"false","checkbox_orientation":"cp-vertical-orien","label_line_height":"1.5","field_animation":"cp-none","field_animation_delay":"0ms","field_animation_duration":"1000ms","width":["105"],"height":["85"]}}}`

The value in checkbox_options is HTML and the HTML has the attribute which is not escaped. The JSON value is already saved in that format in database so I can not control the string but I can replace it or do something and insert it back with the Escaped Attribute.

Is there any way that I can insert it back with escaped attribute.

Also, when I try to json_decode it throws error.

Please need help. I'm struck. Can someone please help?

Comment: How much data do you have that has been stored like this?

Comment: A lot thousands of columns may be.

Comment: `json_decode` throws an error because with those attributes quoted like that, it isn't valid JSON. How did you create that string like that in the first place? Seems like `json_encode` would have escaped it properly.

Comment: Yes, I understand that it is throwing error because of invalid JSON, `json_encode( $decoded_modal_data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE );` I guess because of `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` the data got inserted like that but I'm not sure

Comment: I think `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` should still escape quotes, but I guess that's water under the bridge at this point. By any chance, do all of the JSON values in the database contain exactly the same HTML string, or is it all different?

Comment: They are all different. Also, they don't have the same key as checkbox_options. Some of the HTML is in different key also. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Can we make any preg_replace if there are tags html tags between : and , we can replace the double quotes. Something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Regex to find the bad JSON, PHP's preg_replace_callback will allow you to replace it with a callback where you can modify the string however you think is suitable.

So let's step through that

Regex to find everything between **checkbox_options":** and **",`** which seem to be 2 guaranteed 'before' and 'after' strings. (tested on regexr)

```
$pattern = '(?<=checkbox_options\"\:\")(.*)(?=\"\,\`)';
```

Run preg_replace_callback against your bad json,

```
$goodJson = preg_replace_callback(
    $pattern,
    function ($matches) {
        return fixJson($matches[0]);
    },
    $malformedJson
);
```

Then we'll also need the function to fix your JSON which would be something like:

```
function fixJson($rawHtml) {
  return json_encode($rawHtml); // This section is incomplete
}
```

Please note I haven't implemented the fixJson logic, rather given you the framework to perform your own actions on it.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'll try this and will get back to you!

Comment: You can probably be more efficient by having the logic from fixJson just within the anonymous function, I only separated it out in the example to make the 3 steps clearer. Additionally I don't know if PHP allows positive lookbehinds in PHP, if it doesn't you may just need to re-write the regex to get exactly what you need.

Comment: I know I'm little late, but thank you for such a quick reply. Saved my ass lol. thanks!

Comment: @PreP happy to help buddy. :)